# How to convert a list to tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have a variable to precise the length of the tuple for expl lgt=3
i want to convert this list:

```
list=['Tout', 'le', 'monde', 'aime', 'le', 'chocolat', 'Le', 'est', 'une', 'source', 'agent', 'securité', 'chocolat', 'magnesium']
```

to :

```
('Tout', 'le', 'monde')
('le', 'monde', 'aime')
('monde', 'aime', 'le')
('aime', 'le', 'chocolat')
('le', 'chocolat', 'Le')
('chocolat', 'Le', 'est')
('Le', 'est', 'une')
('est', 'une', 'source')
('une', 'source', 'agent')
('source', 'agent', 'securité')
('agent', 'securité', 'chocolat')
('securité', 'chocolat', 'magnesium')
('chocolat', 'magnesium', '')
```

Comment: simply take the answer from the duplicate link above and change `range(0, len(l), n)` to `range(0, len(l))`

Comment: This question has already been answered : https://stackoverflow.com/a/312464/3626552

Answer (score 0):

The main points:
1. use `tuple(list)`.
2. use slice of list. ex) `list[i:i+3]`.

```
list=['Tout', 'le', 'monde', 'aime', 'le', 'chocolat', 'Le', 'est', 'une', 'source', 'agent', 'securité', 'chocolat', 'magnesium']
tuples = []

list.append('')
lgt = 3
for i in range(len(list)-lgt+1):
    tuples.append(tuple(list[i:i+lgt]))

print (tuples)
```

Refer the following result:

```
[('Tout', 'le', 'monde'), ('le', 'monde', 'aime'), ('monde', 'aime', 'le'), ('aime', 'le', 'chocolat'), ('le', 'chocolat', 'Le'), ('chocolat', 'Le', 'est'), ('Le', 'est', 'une'), ('est', 'une', 'source'), ('une', 'source', 'agent'), ('source', 'agent', 'securité'), ('agent', 'securité', 'chocolat'), ('securité', 'chocolat', 'magnesium'), ('chocolat', 'magnesium', '')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list=['Tout', 'le', 'monde', 'aime', 'le', 'chocolat', 'Le', 'est', 'une', 'source', 'agent', 'securité', 'chocolat', 'magnesium']

print ([tuple(list[i:i + 3]) for i in range(len(list) - 1)])
```

output:

```
[('Tout', 'le', 'monde'), ('le', 'monde', 'aime'), ('monde', 'aime', 'le'), ('aime', 'le', 'chocolat'), ('le', 'chocolat', 'Le'), ('chocolat', 'Le', 'est'), ('Le', 'est', 'une'), ('est', 'une', 'source'), ('une', 'source', 'agent'), ('source', 'agent', 'securité'), ('agent', 'securité', 'chocolat'), ('securité', 'chocolat', 'magnesium'), ('chocolat', 'magnesium')]
```

or:

```
for i in range(len(list)-1):
    print (tuple(list[i:i + 3]))
```

output:

```
('Tout', 'le', 'monde')
('le', 'monde', 'aime')
('monde', 'aime', 'le')
('aime', 'le', 'chocolat')
('le', 'chocolat', 'Le')
('chocolat', 'Le', 'est')
('Le', 'est', 'une')
('est', 'une', 'source')
('une', 'source', 'agent')
('source', 'agent', 'securité')
('agent', 'securité', 'chocolat')
('securité', 'chocolat', 'magnesium')
('chocolat', 'magnesium')
```

Comment: OP wants `('chocolat', 'magnesium', '')` at the last.